# Command Prompt in Administrator mode doesn't see mapped drives

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, network-drive

I am not sure but when I start my Command Prompt in Administrator mode, I can't switch to a mapped drive.  I can do so if I am not in Administrator mode.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: What are the permissions on the network mapped drives?

Comment: That's normal. Map them again in that command prompt. net use driveLetter: \\YourUNChere

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When you start a command prompt "As Administrator" it's running in a different user context than when you don't.

Since mapped drives are user-centric, that Admin user context will not have the (same) drives, and you'll have to map them for that user context once the command window is open as Adminsitrator, e.g. by running `net use <letter>: \\<server>\<share>`. An example:

```
net use Z: \\SuperServer\SuperShare
```

Also, you can enable the `EnableLinkedConnections` flag in the registry to cause the session token to be shared:

> To work around this problem, configure the EnableLinkedConnections
>   registry value. This value enables Windows Vista and Windows 7 to
>   share network connections between the filtered access token and the
>   full administrator access token for a member of the Administrators
>   group.

To do this, set the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLinkedConnections` DWORD flag to `1`, and then reboot your machine.

For more info on that from Microsoft, see: [Some Programs Cannot Access Network Locations When UAC Is Enabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: This workaround has never worked for me and I'm not sure why. Tried on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1. Trying to access Parallels mapped network drives (\\psf\*) from within a Windows VM.

Comment: @JasonDuffett same scenario here. Got it to work with: net use Z: \\psf\Home

Comment: The `EnableLinkedConnections` registry flag does not work for me, on Windows 10. `net use` in an administrator console works.

Comment: Not working for me either on Windows 7 x64 - `net use ...` works fine

Answer (score 16):

This makes me think about an old Windows Vista reported issue.

Can you try:

1. Open RegEdit
2. Go to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. Create a DWORD value named `EnableLinkedConnections` and set it to `1`
4. Reboot the computer
5. Test again

Comment: Yes that didn't work for me in Wondows 10.

Answer (score 10):

One other work-around that took me *ages* to find is to run `net use` from a scheduled task **as the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** account. Apparently [drives mapped under this account show up for all users and all elevation levels](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sfu/2010/05/26/accessing-nfs-shares-through-an-application/).

I've tested this and it works even on NFS shares (which can be a bit finicky). Just create a scheduled task set to run at system startup, and specify the following command:

```
net use \\server\share Z: /persistent:no
```

It might possibly work to run it just once with `/persistent:yes`, but I haven't tried that. Granted, "just map it again" works too, but that drive still won't be visible to scheduled tasks running in different contexts. The downside is that all real users see it too, so not so good for multiuser setups.

Comment: could you add about the method you use to open cmd as "NT Authority\SYSTEM"? I heard that psexec from sysinternals can do that, is that what you are using? And I recall something about task scheduler being able to do it.. maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: @barlop I don't open cmd under that user account; I just create a Scheduled Task and the user account is one of the settings on the General tab.

Comment: @barlop [How to run command as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`](https://superuser.com/a/1709857/)

Comment: The order of arguments is mixed in your example. It should be `net use Z: \\server\share /persistent:no`. In other words, drive letter should come first after `net use`.