# FileZilla not showing network locations

Tags: filezilla

I updated FileZilla using the internal update feature and now I can't see my mapped network shares. How do I fix this?

#### My mapped drives:

[image: My Mapped Drives]

#### FileZilla client:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System
```

Create a new DWORD entry with the name `EnableLinkedConnections` and value `1`.

Comment: FYI, this registry value is ineffective in Windows 10. Not sure about Windows 8, though.

Comment: Strange, I'm running Windows 10 Pro and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Last I tested was November (v1511 without any C.U). Another [user here](http://superuser.com/questions/1031344/running-programs-as-administrator-from-network-drive-windows-10) confirms it doesn't work. Will do more research on this since there have been many updates since then. Thanks for the info.